# How to download value of custom column in kartik grid whose value is calculated by a function

Tags: yii2, grid, export

I have added a custom column in grid whose value is calculated by a function. Everything is working but when I download the grid, this column value is empty. Please guide me how to solve it
**Column in grid is**

```
[
        'label' => 'Arrears',
        'pageSummary'=>true,
        'value' => function ($model) use($monthrange)  {
            return $model->calculatearrears($model, $monthrange);
                    },
        ],
```

Comment: Yes, but how I can I do it?

Comment: How can I add and read the calculated column value through data provider. I have 6 columns which calculated in this way

Comment: Yes, but not in a proper way. I have added an extra column which have same value to its next column and hide it in the grid and download it

Comment: I guess it's still a turnaround. You have provided only a little code and I'm not sure if I can help solving it.